# To display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the information

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

When I User `Window.Location.reload(true)` I am getting the popup message for each and every request. Could any body suggest me how to resolve this Issue?

> To display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the
>   information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of sending data via an HTTP POST (which is most commonly done by submitting a form).  You will either need to stop using a POST or perform an intermediary redirect to remove this message.