# Triggering Gridview event from Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview named `gdLog` and I need to trigger it's `OnNeedDataSource` event. How do you do this from **javascript** or **jQuery**?

I've tried doing a __

```
doPostBack('<%= gdLog.ClientID %>', 'OnNeedDataSource');
```

but it doesn't trigger the event method just a `pageload`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I'm having this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096668/to-display-the-webpage-again-the-web-browser-needs-to-resend-the-information, but by doing window.opener.location.reload(); I'm trying to refresh the gridview data without having to do the reload(). So, basically I have a popup window that changes a value in the database. Once the popup window closes, I need to have the new data show up in the gridview.

Comment: I got it, but I still can't see why are you trying to fire a GridView event.

Comment: If all you want is to refresh the GridView contents, without reloading the page, place it into an UpdatePanel and do it asynchronously.

Comment: Or, the simplest way... `.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment which contains information that should be part of the question, what you're looking for is a way of refreshing the `GridView` with new data, as a result of some change occurred on a popup window.

What do you need maybe can be found in this post:

[Call .NET method asynchronously and bind to grid upon completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238215/call-net-method-asynchronously-and-bind-to-grid-upon-completion)

Or in this article:

http://oakdome.com/programming/ASP_NET_AsyncGridView.php